# Hypothesis Testing - Varying p-value issue in my MWU

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance, p-value, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

[image][image]I have two machines (A & B) in our production line. A is older, B is very new. Both perform the same tasks, except that machine B is advanced and will perform 1 task less than the no of tasks in machine A. For Ex: If machine A performs 5 tasks, then Machine B will accomplish the same in 4 tasks. This should ideally reduce the time taken by machine B to perform the same task. I want to perform a hypothesis test and report the same.

Here is what I have and things I've done so far.

1. Null Hypothesis : There is no significant difference in time taken by both the machines
2. Alternate Hypothesis :  Time taken by Machine B is lower than Machine A
3. No of Records : Machine A (600000), Machine B (500000). Data for 6 months.
4. Distribution : (Extremely) Right skewed, image attached.
5. Performed Python fitter test : These are the probable population distributions in the order for each machine. Machine A (rayleigh, norm, chi2, gamma, exponpow) and machine B (lognorm, cauchy, chi2, expon, exponpow)
6. Outlier : Used IQR method and removed outliers from both population
7. Power analysis for sample size: Used TTestIndPower, with effect = 0.2, alpha = 0.10, power = 0.7. got sample size of 163. (Tested with different values also)
8. Test :  Performed Mann Whitney U test (pingouin.mwu with alternative='less')

The p-value is all over the place from 0.0704 to 0.997. I've tried different permutation and combinations of effect size, power and alpha. But, the same issue in all of them.

I'm thinking of the below, for my next steps.

1. converting all values to log-normal
2. Then removing outliers
3. Performing Two sample T-test

Not sure if it will work. Am I doing something wrong here, what would you advice I check or change or do? Any feedback or advice

Comment: The graph is completely unintelligible to me and so I have no direct impression of the data. I rather doubt that you do too. Perhaps you should can this question and ask instead about how to see the data and then how to understand what it might tell you.

Comment: How are you getting more than one p value? You did one test (in step 8) so you should have one p value.  Also, why remove outliers? Also, with the sample sizes you have, testing will find a singnificant difference even if it is tiny (the power analysis is not really needed here).

Comment: Do not remove outliers until you know what the data are and can justify the omissions on the basis of something other than just their distance from the mode. Search for advice on outliers on this site.

Comment: Oh, and also, what's on the x axis in the graph?  And it doesn't really show anything because of the extreme skew. For outliers, find out why they are outliers. Unless it's a data entry error, you probably shouldn't remove them.

Comment: Michael, about the outliers removal, in this case, I would say that if he has 60k readings from a machine, it is save to remove outliers -- for a simple analysis. The goal, as I see it, is not to get to know what the outliers mean but rather just compare the two machines in terms of their performance (not taking into account their faultless etc.).

Comment: Hypotheses are about population parameters; "significant" refers to a specific sample and is not the target of your inference; in short, the word does not belong in the hypothesis (and indeed that word should probably be avoided altogether if at all possible). Don't use the same data to select your model ("Performed Python fitter test...") and to estimate parameters or test hypotheses. Arbitrary removal of y-outlliers is very likely counterproductive since you're trying to compare means. Why not just choose a more appropriate model for the conditional response, one that accommodates long times

Comment: Mann-Whitney doesn'r require removal of outliers at all, and even otherwise it'd be questionable. Valid informative data should never be removed. Outliers should only be removed if you have strong evidence that they are in fact erroneous. I second the others stating that the graph is hard to grasp and not very helpful.  You could show boxplots and reduce the axis range so that you see what goes on among non-outliers.

Comment: @MikolajBuchwald If the outliers are informative for what the machines do (in very bad situations), they shouldn't be removed. They should only be removed if the information they hold is deemed irrelevant, which usually only is the case if they are erroneous. Also Mann-Whitney isn't sensitive to outliers so removing them will not change matters much anyway.

Comment: By multiple p values, I mean just a different p-value everytime I take a new sample and re run the test.

Comment: Do you use the power analysis in such a way that if it says 163 you use a subset of the data of size 163? That'd be wrong. Use all your data regardless of what the power analysis says. The power analysis gives a *minimum* sample size to reach a certain power. It doesn't say you should use fewer observations than you have.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of the fitter tests.

Comment: @ChristianHennig Yes, I actually used the same sample size that power analysis returned, which is 163. Tbh, I’m new to data science and I read, that sample size should be calculated with power analysis before using it in test. So I did it, not sure if that’s incorrect.

Comment: By the way chances are that with more than 1M observations any test will be significant even if the difference is very small,  unless machine B is actually slower. You will then need to look at the actual difference and decide whether the improvement is actually worthwhile.

Comment: @AKK What you say holds *before you collected a sample* in situations in which sampling is costly, so you'd collect the minimum necessary number of observations according to the power analysis. This doesn't make sense if you already have the observations or collecting more observations comes for free.

Comment: I think there is some mistake in the general framework i have. Could someone please advise the general steps that I should follow to perform the test

Comment: For starters produce a better plot so that we see what you're dealing with. Also if you change the question, update it or ask a new one. Don't add questions in comments.

Comment: @ChristianHennig Thanks, will work on visualuzation first. Apart from that, If the data is right skewed then picking an ideal non parametric test with a large enough sample (frac=0.1 or above), should roughly be the right approach? Sample size does not matter here. Also updated the graph with probability plot Machine A on left.

Comment: Use all the data your have for whatever test, not a fraction. Then you'll have only one p-value as requested by @PeterFlom. Probability plot is for checking normality; not very helpful here as it was clear before that data wouldn't be normal.